# What is the way of detecting android browser in java code?

Tags: java, android, user-agent

I am trying to detect android browser in java.

I know we can sniff the `user agent`(UAgentInfo.java) and detect the device and know whether it is an android device or ios device. But i do not want to detect the device .

What i want to do is that : After detecting the android device, I want to know what kind of browser the user is using. If it is an android browser then i will show another kind of UI .

Is there any way to do it ? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The same thing is included in `user-agent` but you need to search into the whole string for keywords say `mozilla`, `chrome` etc. to see if you can find a match.

Comment: Instead of giving down votes , provide information if you happen to have that on the subject. I don't care about down votes, I am more interested in knowing whether such a thing can be done.

Comment: And I didn't down vote

Comment: @DarshanLila, why not to post your comment as an answer. Because it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing is included in `user-agent` but you need to search into the whole string for keywords say `mozilla`, `chrome` etc. to see if you can find a match.

There can be multiple keywords filter to narrow down your search to exactly detect the type of browser. 
For eg.

```
Mozilla If keywords IN="mozilla","firefox" and NOT IN="IE"
```